# Printing part of a string in PHP similar to the way it is done in Bash?

Tags: php, arrays, string, bash

I have some code below. I want to print part of a string and there are several ways to do it (substr most notably).

But I was curious if there is a Bash-like way of doing it like below (the erroneous code is in comments), where the characters are treated as a character array. The Bash method is simple and elegant (which I always like).

I tried it, PHP did not like it, but maybe there is a syntax that permits this?

```
<?php

    $a ="MontrealistheCapitalofCanada";
    echo "$a";

    // The line below works in Bash and I really like
    // this method because it is simple. 
    // Can this be done in PHP?
    // echo "${a:0:19}";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you can do:

```
echo substr($a, 0, 19);
// prints => MontrealistheCapita
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You will need to operate over the string using string functions or operators.

Comment: Thank you for a concise answer!